# How to log out of SSH session without closing tmux

Tags: session, ssh, tmux

Is there a command I can use to log out of an SSH session where I have tmux running?
Currently, if I want to leave tmux running, I either close the entire window of my ssh session without logging out, or I just let the SSH connection die after inactivity.

But I want to use a command to log out without closing the entire window. If I just type `logout`, then it closes my tmux session and still keeps me logged in to SSH. I then have to type logout again to close the SSH session. But I just want to type one command that disconnects SSH without closing tmux.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>You can set up a new screen that will continue running after you exit SSH. First, run `screen -D -R` over SSH to enter a new screen, then start up tmux. Feel free to just close the terminal window or exit the current screen with Ctrl-A or Ctrl-D. Now, you can always run `screen -D -R` again to go back into the screen you opened earlier.</strike>

EDIT: I'm silly, but the above might help someone who's not using tmux. Check the comments.

Comment: But I'm using tmux so that I don't have to use screen

Comment: Sorry, I totally wasn't thinking about what tmux was. Try typing enter, then `~.` and that should instantly exit your SSH session.

Comment: What should ``<enter> ~.`` do? (I tried it, seems to just say command not found...)

Comment: On most SSH clients, it will instantly exit you out of the SSH connection, regardless of what program is running.

Comment: Woah, that actually worked. That command is very interesting.

Answer (score 45):

First press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> the press <kbd>d</kbd>. This detaches your session. You then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to log out of ssh. Your detached session still keeps running on the server. You can attach it later by `tmux attach-session -t 0` when you log on to server.